# Front wheel shudder on Cyclocross brakes

Tags: brakes

I have a Javelin Primitivo with cantilever brakes. My front fork is carbon.

[image]

When I brake the front wheel will "shudder". I replaced my wheels and adjusted my brakes (toed them in). I have even tried my road bike wheels.

Any thought on solving this? I would like to upgrade my brakes but I want to keep the option for my wide tires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stutter comes from the way the brakes are actuated. From the picture on Javelin's site I see that the housing is held at the top of the head-tube. When you brake the fork flexes backwards causing the cable's tension to change. The brakes will be slightly released causing to fork to move again, re-tightening the brakes, pushing the fork backwards. This happens in quick succession thus the brake stutter. The way to cure it is to move the attachment of the cable-housing to the crown of the fork. There are front cable hangers that can be screwed to the hole where a side-pull brake would be attached.
Google for **'Front Cable Hanger Fork Mount'**

Comment: Thanks I will look when I get home from work tonight. - I will update the answer then

Answer (score 0):

The brake and fork could be at a natural resonance frequency.  Like if you shake a bus pole at just the right frequency you can get it to shake.  Is there any play in the headset or brake?  You can try shortening the pad.  Give up cantilever brakes for a cyclocross means it road bike.  And you need to change out the levers to go side pull.

Comment: Try the answer from Carel (+1).  That takes flex in the fork and headset out of play.

Comment: It will only work if the crown of the fork has a hole for side-pull brakes that can be used for the cable hanger!